# Laravel required_with_all error

Tags: php, laravel-4

Getting the following error when trying to use require_with_all:

Method [validateRequiredWithAll] does not exist.

Validation:

```
            'player6_name' => 'alpha|required_with_all:player6_summoner,player6_position,player6_email',
            'player6_summoner' => 'required_with_all:player6_name,player6_position,player6_email',
            'player6_position' => 'required_with_all:player6_summoner,player6_name,player6_email',
            'player6_email' => 'email|required_with_all:player6_summoner,player6_position,player6_name',
            'player6_student' => '',
            'player6_society' => '',
            'player7_name' => 'alpha|required_with_all:player7_summoner,player7_position,player7_email',
            'player7_summoner' => 'required_with_all:player7_name,player7_position,player7_email',
            'player7_position' => 'required_with_all:player7_summoner,player7_name,player7_email',
            'player7_email' => 'email|required_with_all:player7_summoner,player7_position,player7_name',
            'player7_student' => '',
            'player7_society' => ''),
```

Answer (score 1):

Mabe you are using a different version of laravel, in version 4.1 method validateRequiredWithAll exists and the validation works perfect.

The method is part of the illuminte/validation package but it is not present in verion 4.0 (https://github.com/illuminate/validation/blob/4.0/Validator.php) update to 4.1 if you want to use it.